# Incorrect data occasionally written to disk

Tags: python, file-io, syntax-error

I am working on a Django project which launches a single async thread monitoring the system resources because some requests need to change behaviour based on current state of the server. Code to setup the monitoring thread:

```
def monitor():
    try:
        f = open("file")
        data = eval(f.read())  # raises SyntaxError!?
        f.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = {
            "cpu": [0 for _ in range(720)],
            "ram": [0 for _ in range(720)],
            "disk_capacity": [0 for _ in range(720)],
            "disk_write": [0 for _ in range(720)],
            "disk_read": [0 for _ in range(720)],
            "network_sent": [0 for _ in range(720)],
            "network_recv": [0 for _ in range(720)],
            "uptime": 0
        }

    while True:
        f = open("file", "w")
        f.write(str(data))
        f.close()
        data = update_data(data)  # Returns every full hour

class ServerStatusConfig(AppConfig):
    ...

    def ready(self):
        # Workaround for Django's process forking
        try:
            f = open("temp", "r")
            f.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            f = open("temp", "w")
            f.close()
            thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor)
            thread.start()
        else:
            os.remove("temp")

def update_data(data):
    # Fetch cpu, ram, dskcap, dskw, dskr, netr, nets
    # cpu scheduled to calculate average until next full hour,
    # other stats are fetched immediately afterwards
    ...
    data["cpu"] = data["cpu"][1:]+[cpu]
    data["ram"] = data["ram"][1:]+[ram]
    data["disk_capacity"] = data["disk_capacity"][1:]+[dskcap]
    data["disk_write"] = data["disk_write"][1:]+[dskw]
    data["disk_read"] = data["disk_read"][1:]+[dskr]
    data["network_recv"] = data["network_recv"][1:]+[netr]
    data["network_sent"] = data["network_sent"][1:]+[nets]

    return data
```

Basically, reading the `str(data)` from file which is not read from nor written to by any other code raises a SyntaxError every so often. Syntax Error in the file is **always** caused by additional `]}` at the end of the file. That means that the data is recoverable and that this does technically fixes the problem:

```
except SyntaxError:
    data = eval(f.read()[:-2])
```

But what could be the cause for occasionally writing incorrect data to a file?

**Edit**: Updated code to display `data` dictionary contents on creation time.

**Edit**: Updated code to display `update_data` function.

Comment: Can we see the file content? Is a Python file? Why are you using `eval`? There's always a different, better method than using `eval`.

Comment: The code, that generates `data` could erroneously add the trailing `]}`. Can we see it? I mean this part: `except FileNotFoundError:
        data = {...}`

Comment: And what does update_data() do?